# using me and I in a sentence

Tags: grammaticality

Which one is technically correct and most used:

“John and me are going to the store.”

or

“John and I are going to the store.”

Comment: Note, "technically correct" and "most used" can be opposites.

Comment: And 'technically correct' is ill-defined, as it depends on whose technique / style-guide you choose to prioritise.